# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" in django

Tags: django

I am newbie to django and using it as  back end for an application that creates users. In front end the code for posting the user name is :

```
var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
              xobj.open('POST', "http://www.local:8000/create_user/", true);
                xobj.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
              xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                      console.log(xobj.responseText);
                  }
            }
              xobj.send(json);
```

On back end the function associated with url handles json but i am getting the error
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.local:54521' is therefore not allowed access".
What is the solution for this problem?
Also I have followed the steps from "https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619", but problem persists.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your front and back end are on different ports which means your ajax requests are subject to cross origin security.

You need to set up the back end to accept requests from different origins (or just different port numbers).

Try reading up on [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and more specifically looking at [django cors headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

Answer (score 104):

Here's what I did when I got the same error from Django Rest Framework while sending an API request from Restangular.
What this does is add CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to responses from Django Rest Framework. Not having CORS headers was the cause of the error.

In the Django Project root folder (where the manage.py file is located), do:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

I tried it using virtualenv but was not able to get it to work, so I installed it without switching to virtualenv and got it installed.

After installing it, you have to make some edits to your django settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Setting above to true allows all origins to be accepted.

References: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: Thanks so much! Also needed to send the request with "withCredentials: true" (For AngularJS thats: $http(url, {withCredentials:true}).get() )

Comment: Awesome! But consider read tutorial on git, you may want to specify some specifics origins and not "ALLOW_ALL".

Comment: Note: The git README file states (**incorrectly**), that the MIDDLE ware edits are required for Django < 1.10. However this is not true. You will still need to add the cors middleware in order for it to work with Django 1.10

Comment: Did not work for me for `django 2.1.4` and `django-cors-headers 2.4.0` which are both the latest versions at the time of writing.

Comment: I get 500 error, when i put 'corsheaders' in INSTALLED_APPS. any solution for that?

Comment: Does not this method create security hole?

Answer (score 52):

In my case, I had simply forgotten to add a trailing slash at the end of the REST API URL. ie,
I had this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login
```

Instead of this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: This fixed my problem too...can't believe I did that.

Comment: What!! I spent nearly 2 days trying to figure this out! Can anyone explain why this happens?
Thank you so much!!

Comment: It's absolutely insane that this solved my problem as well. No error messages pointed in that direction really

Answer (score 16):

If using django for backend, you need to do the following 6 things:

- ensure you are in the virtualenv, then 'pip install django-cors-headers'
- add the following in your INSTALLED-APPS section of the settings.py:
  'corsheaders',
- add the following in the MIDDLEWARE section of the settings.py:
  `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'`,  
  `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'`,
- add either of the following at the bottom of the settings.py: 
  `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` or

  ```
  CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
  'http://localhost:3000',
  'http://127.0.0.1:3000'
  ]
  ```
- When using CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST, use the URL of the front end app where the GET Or POST request is coming from.
- Another gotcha is ensuring the URL pointing to django ends with a trailing slash.

Comment: thanks alot, the last point was really helpfull

Comment: thanks for your useful answer, my problem got solved

Answer (score 8):

If `django-cors-headers` not resolved the problem try manual add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def swanger(request):
  resutl = {'a': 1}
  resp = JsonResponse(resutl)
  resp['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  return resp
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue.

**user3785412**'s answer will work. but, first time it may not work directly because of **browser cache**. either try in **another browser** or **clear cache** before loosing hope.

I had API server in **Django 2** hosted on Heroku and **Angular 7** Client on Firebase.
I made all changes in settings.py as per user3785412 and still it would not work, wasted almost 3 hours. Then came across on post which suggested **cache could be issue**. opened in chrome and *voila*!

Hope this helps! *(My first answer here, please go easy)*

Answer (score 3):

I have observed this error in 3 scenarios:

1. When the URL didn't end with `/`.
2. When URL had slashes like `//` or `///`.
3. When my server was not working. But after switching it on it worked fine.

Comment: Oh my god, point 1 was the main issue, for which I spent hours, why everything was not working for me

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was localhost:8000 while 127.0.0.1 was expected... changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in my browser did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in middleware classes

> ```
> 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware'
> ```

so overall implementation would be:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware'

    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

check [documentaion](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/2.1.0/)  below for more info

Comment: Something worth to mention here. The **CorsMiddleware**  in the **MIDDLEWARE** list should come before any other middleware that might handle requests/response processing. Otherwise, the cors error will still persist.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I'm not seeing this solution, which worked for me, anywhere. So hoping this can be helpful for someone.

Cross-origin requests in this context are only possible if the partner site's server allows it through their response headers.

I got this to work in Django **without any CORS middleware** by setting the following headers on the response:

```
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "requesting_site.com"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET"
response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "requesting_site.com"
```

Most answers on StackOverflow seem to mention the first one, **but not the second two**. I've just confirmed they are all required. You'll want to modify as needed for your framework or request method (GET, POST, OPTION).

p.s. You can try `"*"` instead of `"requesting_site.com"` for initial development just to get it working, but it would be a security hole to allow every site access. Once working, you can restrict it for your requesting site only to make sure you don't have any formatting typos.

Comment: +1. For some cases, `Allow-Origin` is enough. For those where it isn't, trying `Allow-Methods` in addition will solve some. For my case, `-Origin` was not enough to avoid `PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader` CORS error, but adding `-Method` with the relevant methods for that endpoint was the key.

Answer (score 0):

i was using python 2.7 and due to some reasons i cannot change the python version
to version 3 and it took me 3 hours to find a solution which is :

```
response =  HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = '*'
response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = 'GET,PUT, OPTIONS'
response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '1000'
response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `redirect: 'follow'` to the headers on the client

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://www.example.com/auth/token/login/", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the above answers with favs but all not work. When I read again the terminal prompts and I found a warning: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is not compatible to the debug environment, use `MIDDLEWARE`. I found the MIDDLEWARE settings and add `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',` to it and it worked.

Sigh