# Ionic and Django: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: django, api, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, ionic2

I'm building my first app with Ionic and I'm using Django Rest Framework as API.

I just want to create a simple page in Ionic that shows a list of categories.

I've created the model Category, and the ViewSets for the API. When I go to the Django-rest-framwork viewer (http://localhost:3010/category/) everything works fine.

But when I try to get the results (with Ionic) I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3010/category/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My code:

```
import {Page, Platform, NavController} from 'ionic/ionic';
import {EmployeeDetailsPage} from '../employee-details/employee-details';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/getting-started/getting-started.html'
})
export class GettingStartedPage {
  constructor(platform: Platform, nav: NavController, http: Http) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.nav = nav;
    this.http = http;

    this.http.get("http://localhost:3010/category/")
        .subscribe(data =>{
          this.items=JSON.parse(data._body).results;//Bind data to items object  
        },error=>{
            console.log(error);// Error getting the data
        } );

  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476273/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send CORS headers to Ionic Framework to let cross-domain ajax work, since your ionic app is hosted on port 8100, and django-server is running on port 3010, this is considered a cross-domain request.

For django, install [CORS headers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cors-headers) app through pip.

In your settings, enable 'corsheaders' app, and also add the allowed urls.

```
# this disables Cross domain requests
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False 

# this allows cookie being passed cross domain    
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True 

# this is the list of allowed origins for cross domain ajax
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ( 
        'localhost:8100',

)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to install [CORS](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers).

If you are testing on chrome you might also need to allow cross origin (There is an extension for it) which should get you around the CORS issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the extensión.