# HttpResponse not returning anything in POST

Tags: python, json, django

I'm new to Django so please excuse me if this is a silly question. I'm trying to create a very simple REST API where a file gets sent via POST and Django returns a json string.

Here is my code in views.py:

```
def evaluate(request):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"hello world": 123}))
```

And in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^evaluate/$', csrf_exempt(views.evaluate), name='evaluate'),
]
```

When I do a GET request to /evaluate/ I get back `{"hello world": 123}`, however I receive a blank response when I send the exact same request as a POST.

Any ideas how I can have POST requests return the JSON as well?

Comment: the view looks fine to me. how are you sending POST request? what is the status code for the response?

Comment: I simply get back "Could not get any response" when I use Postman to send a request, or "This request has no response data available." in Google Chrome's developer tools under Network->XHR. However, when I add `print("hello world")` it will show up in the console in both GET and POST requests

Comment: Have you tried to use curl in your linux command? `curl -X POST https://yourdomain.com/evaluate`?

Comment: curl worked. I did a little further investigation and found out that it was CORS on Chrome that was causing the issue. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I did a little further investigation and found out that it was CORS on Chrome that was causing the issue. Here's a link to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30956822/563762