# Error in receiving data from the Django REST API

Tags: python, django, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a mobile app made with ionic2 and Angularjs2.

I am running my Django on localhost i.e http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/
this url returns JSON Data as shown below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ticker": "FB",
        "open": 7.0,
        "close": 10.0,
        "volume": 500
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "ticker": "AMZN",
        "open": 125.05,
        "close": 200.98,
        "volume": 800
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "ticker": "MSFT",
        "open": 1.25,
        "close": 87.0,
        "volume": 7000
    }
]
```

I am using a provider in my app to get the data from the URL

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class GetData {


  public data:any;
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello GetData Provider');
  }

  load(){
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }



    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
    });

  }

}
```

this provider I am using in my page to receive the data and show

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {GetData} from '../../providers/get-data';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public recvData:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public getData: GetData) {
    this.loadPeople();
  }
  loadPeople(){
    this.getData.load()
    .then(data => {
      this.recvData = data;
    });

    console.log("the received data is >> ",this.recvData);
  }


}
```

and using it in my HTML page like this

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor='let stock of recvData'>
                <p>stock.ticker</p>
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

And I am getting this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8000/stocks/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.`

main.js:43460EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null

Comment: Your frontend and backend are working on different ports which makes this a `Cross Origin` request. You should allow this behavior in django as it is not allowed by default. Have a look at `django-cors-middleware` for allowing Cross-Origin requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476273/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-i)

Comment: Thanks sir ...i just used the CORS extension to make it work.
i already had the CORS extension but it was disabled.
i am using this extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: you need to pass exact url in variable CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=(<path>) to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on your Django app.

You can archieve that using [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) with Django.

After you install the package add `http://localhost:8100` to whitelist.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8100',
)
```