# CORES django-react application

Tags: python, django, reactjs, nginx

Getting issue on api  call

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed 
access.
```

My react app is running at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' and django api app at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476273/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-i)

Comment: Failed to load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.