# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on the requested resource in Django

Tags: django, otree

I have read relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476273/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-i) and understand what is cors.

I followed each step.

Install

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Add

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'a9.core.access.middleware.AccessMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

INSTALLED_APPS = ['corsheaders','otree']
```

And

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

However, I still get the error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.1

Is there something I am missing to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Using `127.0.0.1` **NOT** `localhost` did the trik.